# Reading white spaces from a text file into Char/String array

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, char, whitespace

I am trying to read and create a multi-dimensional array of **char**(not possible?) or **String** from a text file splitting each char/symbol/space.

Text file containing below two lines 2x10 :

```
abcd  x/@#
% addk a 2
```

I want the array slots to either contain the empty space or at least a replace it with pre-defined character.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("files/myFile.txt"));
for(int i=0; i<2; ++i)
{
    for(int j=0; j<10; ++j)
    {
        chars[i][j] = br.readLine().charAt(j);

    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I meant sorry, will fix the typo

Comment: Small comment. You CAN create arrays with chars, you can get it from your string with toCharArray()

Comment: do you always know how many lines will be in file?

Comment: yes I will know the number of lines Pshemo

Comment: Then Hovercraft gave you perfect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String's `toCharArray()` will likely solve your problem. Call it on each line read and feed it into each row of your array of char[][].

```
// in constants declaration
public final static int ROWS = 2;
public final static int COLS = 10;

// somewhere else in your code.
char[][] chars = new char[ROWS][COLS];

// making sure to catch exceptions with opening and reading file
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("files/myFile.txt"));

for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
  String line = br.readLine();

  // check line exists, has a length of COLS, else throw exception.

  chars[i] = line.toCharArray();
}
```

ROWS and COLS are program constants, and you'd better make darn sure that these numbers are correct, else this code will go down in flames. Better to use `List<List<Character>>` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains an error, every time you use `br.readLine()` its going to read a new line, hence move br.readLine() to outer loop and use this string to find char at position j.